# ReportViewer 2008 switch to different page sizes

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, reporting-services, reportviewer

My deployed application uses ReportViewer (CLR 3.5) to print locally reports.

Recently users noticed problem with printing.
I've investigated that and turned out that in some PC reportViewer set page format to Letter (instead A4) that's why printouts are cut.

Note all user use same network-deployed version with same ReportViewer dlls. RDLCs are properly set to A4 size...

Any advice how to force using same standard (A4 for all app instances), and what produced format depends for?

**EDIT:**

Turned out it wasnt just printer settings / driver problem

Finally fixed by setting Print Layout by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page size for both printing and display is stored in the RDL file itself, so if only certain clients are printing at the wrong size, then I suspect that their printer settings are incorrect.

Comment: It was printer driver problem. Fixed when PCL driver installed. Thanks for tip

Answer (score 1):

Is the printer set to A4 as default?  If possible, does the page size change when exported to pdf?